# Empty attribute with Ruby HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm implementing Schema microformats on a Ruby project using HAML and can't figure out how to set an empty attribute on a tag. I tried nil and false, but they simply do not shown.

Example: `<div itemscope>`

I'm tring to set an empty itemscope attribute.

#### Code added from comment by @StrangeElement:

My code:

```
.agency.premium{:itemscope => true, :itemtype => 'schema.org/ProfessionalService';}
```

`:itemscope => true` seems to be the recommended approach from HAML's documentation. I get the same result as I would get with `:itemscope => ''`, a XHTML-valid attribute with an empty value (i.e. `<div itemscope="">`).

Probably fine, but I'd rather have it empty as is documented in the Schema doc.

Comment: Could you paste your Haml code please?

Comment: Have you tried an empty string? `%span{ :itemscope => '' }`

Comment: My code: .agency.premium{:itemscope => true, :itemtype => 'http://schema.org/ProfessionalService'}.

    :itemscope => true seems to be the recommended approach from HAML's documentation. I get the same result as I would get with :itemscope => '', a XHTML-valid attribute with an empty value (i.e. <div itemscope="">). Probably fine, but I'd rather have it empty as is documented in the Schem adoc.

Comment: In your post, wrap your markup with ` (backtick) characters so it'll be visible.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Using something like

```
%div{:itemscope => true}
```

is the correct way to specify this in your Haml file.

How this is rendered depends on how you set Haml's [`format` option](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#format-option). The default in Haml 3.1 is `xhtml`, and with that it will render as `itemprop='itemprop'`, which is valid xhtml. To render with minimized attributes (like `<div itemscope>`) you need to set the format to `html4` or `html5`. (In Rails 3 the default is `html5`, and in Haml 4.0 the default is `html5`).

How to set the Haml options depends on how you are using it, see the [options section in the docs](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#options).

For example, using Haml directly in Ruby, this:

```
engine = Haml::Engine.new '%div{:itemscope => true}'
puts engine.render
```

produces the default xhtml with full attributes:

```
<div itemscope='itemscope'></div>
```

But this:

```
engine = Haml::Engine.new '%div{:itemscope => true}', :format => :html5
puts engine.render
```

produces the desired result with minimized attributes:

```
<div itemscope></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested in how to put more words in that way, he may use `"foo bar" => true`:

```
%option{ "disabled selected value" => true } Choose an option
```

results is:

```
<option disabled="" selected="" value="">Choose an option</option>
```

and works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works, but it produces an HTML attribute with value.

If you want the attribute only to be output on HTML, without value, you can use the [HTML-style attributes syntax of HAML](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#html-style-attributes-):

```
%div(itemscope)
```