# Downloading a file when an anchor tag is clicked in HAML

Tags: file, download, click, anchor, haml

You can do this in HTML by setting the `href` to the a file's path and giving it a download attribute like so:

```
<a href="images/file.png" download>
```

Note that the download attribute doesn't need to be set to anything.

However, the way attributes work in HAML is different and giving it a download parameter that isn't set to anything causes an error.

```
%a{:href => "images/file.png", :download}
```

"syntax error, unexpected ')'"

I tried actually setting the download to something but for whatever reason it just redirects to the file as if it doesn't exist.

Comment: This answer might have the info you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6247375/514040

Comment: Seems unnecessarily convoluted, I'd prefer to just make the download attribute work.

Comment: Given the way HAML works I'm not sure you'll find anything simpler. Besides, how hard is it to do `:download => true` vs. just `:download`? (admittedly you also have to change a bit of configuration if it doesn't render the way you want, but you seem to want html output which should be the default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work with 
`%a{:href => file, :download => file, :target => "blank"}` all in tandem